# A curious inequality concerning binomial coefficients

Tags: inequalities, binomial-coefficients

Has anyone seen an inequality of this form before? It seems to be true (based on extensive testing), but I am not able to prove it.

Let $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_k$ be non-negative integers such that $\sum_i a_i = A$. Then, for any non-negative integer $B \le A$:
$$
\sum_{(b_1,\ldots,b_k): \sum_i b_i = B} \prod_i \frac{\binom{a_i}{b_i}}{\binom{A-a_i}{B-b_i}} \ge {\binom{A}{B}}^{2-k}.
$$
The sum on the left is over all tuples $(b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_k)$ of non-negative integers, with $b_i \le a_i$ for all $i$, whose sum is equal to $B$.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By Cauchy–Bunyakovsky–Schwarz inequality we have
$$
\left(\sum \prod_i \frac{\binom{a_i}{b_i}}{\binom{A-a_i}{B-b_i}}\right)\left(\sum\prod_i \binom{a_i}{b_i}\binom{A-a_i}{B-b_i}\right)\geqslant 
\left(\sum \prod_i\binom{a_i}{b_i}\right)^2=\binom{A}{B}^2
.$$

Thus it suffices to prove that 
$$
\sum\prod_i \binom{a_i}{b_i}\binom{A-a_i}{B-b_i}\leqslant \binom{A}B^k.
$$
But RHS is just the sum of the same guys without the restriction $\sum b_i=B$.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you.